# Sql Database Project that extends existing table

Tags: sql-server, ssms, database-project, dacpac

I have a 'Core' VS Database project, that includes a table called [dbo].[MyTable], with a number of columns on it. I reuse this project in a number of solutions, where I also include an application-specific Database project that references the core database project, and adds more tables and FKs from those tables onto the tables in the core project.

Is it possible to 'build on' tables defined in the core db project, that is to add more columns to an existing table, so that those columns are only defined for one application-specific db project and not any of the others that reuse the same core db project?

Edit: I have just found the same question posted over 6 years ago. Apparently, back then the answer was 'no', but maybe it is possible in newer versions of VS?

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3583a5ea-d653-4268-a1d0-f58788c0cebf/partial-project-add-extra-column-to-table?forum=vstsdb

Comment: Actually, it's *still* the wrong question. You are mixing up ER concepts like inheritance with relational concepts - these are *different* things. A database project represents a *relational* model, not ER. ER does have inheritance, real types and relations with attributes. These get *mapped* to a relational model. The Database project in Visual Studio (or any other DB tool) isn't an ER model of the database, it's the final result.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say - what do you suggest I should be doing?

Comment: Either use an ER modelling tool that offers inheritance and *mapping it* to a relational model, or create the tables by hand. What you are asking simply has no meaning for a Database project.

Comment: It's a good question, it's not about 'inheritance' it is just about structuring the code files, so that you have two .sql files that describe a table and the tooling combines them for you when you deploy. It would be a good feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can add columns in a post-deploy script, but the unfortunate thing is that you cannot reference these columns else where in the project.  So in my post-deploy script for the specific instance of the project I would check for the existence of the table and of the column, and if the column does not exist I would add it.  However that column added by script won't be added to the data model for you to reference elsewhere via another stored procedure or view.

A possible workaround might be to leave your core table as is, in the core project.  In the extension project create a table, with the appropriate foreign keys and constraints back to the core table, along with the additional column(s), effectively a 1:1 relationship.  And if necessary virtualize the two tables with a VIEW, that contains the core columns, plus the additional columns from the extension table.

If the core is standardized across all instances, you want to keep the core that way.  think of those extensions as part of the rules of separation of responsibility.  if the core ever changes, it should only impact the core, and if the extensions ever need to change, only those should be changed.

Comment: Yes, this is what we've decided to do - basically, I think the answer to my question is that it is (still) not possible to extend tables in DB projects that reference other DB projects. So the only options available are to either extend via a post-deployment script, or define an extension table with a 1:1 mapping to the core table (and optionally interact via a view that combines the 2)

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for something like table inheritance.  This is supported by Postgres (see the documentation [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html)).  And it seems to be exactly what you describe.

If so, then SQL Server does not support it directly.  My advice would be to have the core table and then for each application have another table with the same clustered index for the additional columns.

Comment: Hi, I'm not looking for table inheritance support in SQL Server, I'm looking for inheritance support at design-time in Visual Studio Database projects - the output of which would be just a normal table but with the columns defined in the base project plus the columns added to it in the application-specific project

Comment: Hi again, could you also explain how you configure using the same clustered index for the additional columns in the 'extension' table please?

Comment: @SimonGreen you are asking the wrong question and mixing up relational and ER concepts. ER does have inheritance but that gets *mapped* to the final relational constucts in various ways (table per type, table per hierarchy etc). A VS database project contains the relational constructs, not the ER model.

Comment: @Panagiotis, I'm not asking about ER concepts. This question has nothing to do with C# or VB classes, for example. Inheritance is a bad word to use in this problem, it's obviously misleadng. It's quite hard to explain the problem I guess, but I'm trying to design the reusable columns of a given table in a base VS DB project, and then design some additional columns for that table in a application-specific VS DB project that refers to the base VS DB Project

Comment: It's not possible in SSDT. You'd need to make a separate table per partial project if I understand what you're wanting to do correctly. You can't define most of a table in the base project and then tweak it in sub-projects.  As others have noted, your best bet is probably a "helper" table of some sort, clustered on the joining columns, containing the ID of the base table and whatever extra columns you need for your particular sub-project.